# Magento2 Get product custom options on product list page

Tags: magento2.2

```
$customOptions = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Option')
    ->getProductOptionCollection($_product);

if (empty($customOptions)) { //check if product has custom options. If it doesn't go to the next product
    continue;
}

foreach($customOptions as $option) {
    $values = $option->getValues();
    if (empty($values)) { //check if option has values (Option can have values only if option type is checkbox, radio, multiselect or drop-down)
        continue;
    }

    foreach($values as $value) {
        $valueData = $value->getData(); //do whatever you want will value data
    }
}
```

I try this code but not working ?!

Answer (score 0):

This code is working for me

```
$customOptions = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Option')
    ->getProductOptionCollection($_product);

if (!empty($customOptions->getData())) {
    foreach ($customOptions->getData() as $option) {
    print_r($option); // do whatever in your option

    }
}
```

Comment: Same result nothing  ?

Comment: exactly where you put this code

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: objectManager

Comment: You have to instantiate the object manager, but as a quick action you can get it like this  $objectManager=   \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

Comment: ok but still not print any thing in list page

Comment: I put it after  <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getProductPrice($_product) ?>